# Hadoop Cygwin Windows 7 JAVA_HOME Path not found and command not found

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, cygpath

i have tried all possible solutions through google but still not working
i am not getting what is this command not found error from hadoop-env.sh and bin/java not such a directory,

**Here is hadoop-env.sh**

export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Java/jre6

export JAVA_HOME=c:/Java/jre6

**Here is my error bellow**

-bash-4.1$ bin/hadoop namenode -format

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 15: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 18: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 22: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 32: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 35: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 38: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 41: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 44: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 49: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: $'\r': command not found

/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 58: $'\r': command not found

/bin/java: No such file or directory

/bin/java: No such file or directory

/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to environment variable and then advance setting
Go to user variable and setVariable  **JAVA_HOME** and there Value **C:\Java\sunjdk6.0.24**
Then go to **Path** and set  cygwin path   **c:\cygwin\bin;c:\cygwin\usr\bin**

DO it if not done erlier, If you still facing problem then see [Link](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/09%20-%20unpack%20hadoop.html) for Hadoop installation on windows and follow every steps.

Comment: Thank you! I had set Java to a PATH variable but not Cygwin. No wonder my system still wasn't finding what it needed!

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Actually, I have this similar error.

Comment: @ChrisSu Did you check the **Link**.What java version you are using.What is your cgywin location.

Comment: @s.singh Hi, thanks for your response. Yes. I followed the link's procedure. My cgywin location is exactly the same. c:\cygwin\bin. Please take a look at my Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170317/hadoop-installation-no-such-file-while-run-hadoop-format