# Hadoop Installation: No such file while run hadoop format

Tags: hadoop

I've checked answers on stackoverflow, no solutions work for my case.

Command:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Error Message:

```
/bin/java: No such file or directory1.7.0_09/
/bin/java: No such file or directory1.7.0_09/
/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Relevant change in **hadoop_env.sh**

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_09/
```

I use soft-link by

```
ln -s "c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_09" /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_09
```

Java HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
```

Path :

```
C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\cygwin64\usr\sbin
```

If any one has clues, please feel free to point it out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe, what is **sbin** in **C:\cygwin64\usr\sbin**. I think it should be **C:\cygwin64\usr\bin**

Comment: @s.singh I'm using hadoop 0.20.2. So there is no /usr/bin, only /usr/sbin

Comment: @s.singh Sorry. /usr/sbin is only directory in cygwin64. It's not related with hadoop. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xhudik @s.singh Finally! There is a problem when modifying hadoop_env.sh in Windows. I've fixed the problem with dos2unix command to eliminate dos style character. 
If dos2unix command can't be found in cygwin, re-download cygwin and update it.

Please follow the link here:

https://superuser.com/questions/612435/cygwin-dos2unix-command-not-found

The command is

```
dos2unix hadoop_env.sh
```

Then everything is all set. Hope my experience would help others. 
Thanks for s.singh and xhudik's help.

Comment: This is really tricky, when you edited it using text editor like gedit, it is hard to find that there is a letter ^M at the end of each line. So always use vi to edit these configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

**there is no java**. Are you sure that your java binaries (./java , ./javac...) are in the specified directories? Maybe ln is a problem. Java also doesn't like " " in directory name (c:\program files) ...

You need to correctly place java distribution and then define **JAVA_HOME** variable. You can test it by:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes. I've tried the command you provided. The binaries are there.

Comment: java is not there if you got: /bin/java: No such file or directory1.7.0_09/ . Try to put java into some different directory, best would be directly to some cygwin dir

Comment: Yea. It's most likely that the environment hasn't been configured correctly. I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set your java home like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.7.0_09 in hadoop_env.sh
```

also you need to set Java Path in environment variable for java.
If still getting issue, then please let us know.

For learning and best practice on hadoop, try using cloudera version or Hortonworks version of hadoop . You can download their windows version. Please check link:
[hortonworks.](http://hortonworks.com/blog/installing-hadoop-on-windows/)
[cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html)

Or you can use IBM Smart Cloud enterprise. IBM is giving free access for students and learning.

Comment: I've already tried that. But it seems not working. Hadoop can't read " " in the path. i.e. Program Files. It only reads Program